# Ember - how to display a list of checkbox related to an array using CollectionView?

Tags: ember.js

I have an application with items.
I would like to display checkboxes for a list of values in an item.

I use a Checkbox to do this:

```
App.DisplayedValueCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
    itemValuesBinding: 'parentView.item.values',

    checked: function () {
        return true; //Default value is always true
    }.property('content', 'itemValues.@each'),

    click: function (evt) {
       //update graph
     }
});
```

And try to display it into a collection view:

```
App.DisplayedValuesView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.Item.values'
    ,itemBinding: 'App.Item'
    , tagName: 'ul'
    , itemViewClass: Em.View.extend({
        itemBinding: 'parentView.item'
        , templatename: 'displayed-values'
    })
});
```

which is part of a parent view:

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="item">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <hr><p>{{desc}}</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                {{#each item in values}}
                <li>{{item}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <div>{{view App.DisplayedValuesView}}</div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

But the view does not display the checkboxes <strike>and there is an error:</strike>

<strike>`Unable to find view at path 'App.DisplayedValuesView'`</strike>

**Edit:** this error was corrected thank to @sly7_7's answer

Here is the [jsFiddle of this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/lauhub/vLnWL/)

I know I miss something, but what ?

Something in the bindings (I am not sure how they work) ?

Should I write a specific Route (`App.ItemRoute = ...`) ?

Defining the checkbox view ? The template ?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that your declare your App as a local var. Ember/Handlebars helpers needs global when you want to reference a view from the application namespace.
So just remove the 'var' before App :)

Comment: OK, thanks, this removes the error! But the DisplayedValuesView still displays nothing :(